# Should Reacts `propTypes` and `defaultProps` be used in conjunction with Flowtype, or is Flowtype comprehensive enough?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, react-proptypes

Thinking of a simple example such as:

```
class CommentAreaComponent extends React.Component {
static propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
};

static defaultProps = {
    loading: false,
};
```

In the constructor I can define something like this to achieve (I think) the same thing:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor({
        loading = false,
    }:{ 
        id:string, 
        loading?:boolean 
    }) {
        super(arguments[0]);
    }
}
```

The second example is using only Flowtype. Does using Reacts PropTypes and DefaultProps offer an advantage? Or can I drop them completely when using FlowType?

Comment: I use TypeScript instead of Flow, but it's a similar situation. I've found that you can really skip the `propTypes` when writing code, but one difference is that `propTypes` will be analyzed at runtime, so if you are doing anything really dynamic that Flow can't predict, `propTypes` might help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can surely use Flow types instead of React PropTypes, but your proposed syntax is not the common way to do it. See [Flow docs](http://flowtype.org/docs/react.html) (scroll down for ES6 syntax):

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  props: {
    title: string,
    visited: boolean,
    onClick: () => void,
  };

  state: {
    display: 'static' | 'hover' | 'active';
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    visited: false,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      display: 'static',
    };
  }

  render() {
    let className = 'button ' + this.state.display;
    if (this.props.visited) {
      //...
    }

    return (/*...*/);
  }
}
```

The only thing you can't do with Flow types that you can do with PropTypes is defining [custom validators](http://www.ian-thomas.net/custom-proptype-validation-with-react/) (e.g. to check that a prop is a valid email).

I have more [Flow React examples on github](https://github.com/raquo/facebook-flow-examples/tree/master/examples/react), but I didn't test them with Flow v0.22 yet, only v0.21. They might need minor adjustments.

Comment: This doesn't validate your `defaultProps`. If you set your `visited` defaultProp to "123", flow will not tell you it's an invalid type.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, Flow's static analysis will give you greater power and greater reach, and is thus preferable to `propTypes`.

However, `propTypes` are still nice in cases where you may be object-spreading props down through multiple components, or in other dynamic runtime scenarios where props might not have the values you expect.

Consider getting the best of both with https://github.com/brigand/babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes

NOTE: I am not affiliated with this library.

Comment: I've been using the aforementioned library for a while, and while the concept sounds great, in reality it unfortunately doesn't work very well. It doesn't support all types of React components, doesn't work with React Native at all as of version 0.39, and is very fragile in general. More importantly, it no longer seems to be maintained enough for such issues to be resolved in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I'm using `babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes` and it seems to be well maintained for my use on the web.